# How to run command over ssh without clobbering stdin for subsequent curl command?

Tags: ssh, stdin

This bash script is supposed to fetch a token from elsewhere via ssh, then run a curl command where it reads data from a file on stdin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TOKEN=$(ssh somewhere cat sometoken.txt)
curl https://example.com \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "someparam=@-" \
  -X POST
```

And the script is called like this:

```
cat somefile | myscript
```

When I hardcode `TOKEN=abcd123` instead of using `$(ssh ...)`, `somefile` is uploaded as expected by curl.

However when I use `$(ssh ...)` my file is not uploaded.

I assume that my script's stdin is being clobbered by `$(ssh ...)` but I can't see how to work around that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the ssh has completed in the script? Is it waiting for a password? Also, I think you want `cat` instead of `echo` :).

Comment: I'm sure ssh has completed because I can add an `echo $TOKEN` before the `curl` and it writes it out on stdout.  You're right about `cat` v `echo` - though neither is the command I actually run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, use `ssh -n ...`

The `ssh` tool reads all data from standard input.  It does this to be able to pass it on to any command that you are executing on the remote side (you could use `ssh remote 'cat >out' <in` to copy the contents of a file to a remote system if you so wished).

With its `-n` option, you tell it to not do that.  It would be more or less equivalent to redirecting `/dev/null` into its standard input by doing `ssh ... </dev/null`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works!

Comment: And thank you for the clear explanation.